# C# - F# interoperability, how to get result instead of FSharpFunc

Tags: c#, f#, sequence, ienumerable, language-interoperability

I'm learning F# and would like to write simple F# library which can be consumed from C# application. It works as expected for trivial F# functions e.g.

```
let Square x = x * x
```

From C# I can consume it and get the expected value:

```
var sqaredNumber = MyFSharpLibrary.Square(5);
```

However when I use a `Sequence` / `IEnumerable<T>` as function parameter I got `FSharpFunc` object instead of the result.
Here is my function:

```
let FilterEvenNumbers input = Seq.filter(fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
```

And this is how I try to use it from C# code:

```
 var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 var filteredNumbers = MyFSharpLibrary.FilterEvenNumbers(numbers);
```

Instead of value `filteredNumbers` contains `FSharpFunc` object. I could use method `Invoke` on that object but would like to avoid extra complexity.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your function declaration returns a function. If you enter it into `dotnet fsi` you'll see the signature:

```
val FilterEvenNumbers: input: 'a -> (seq<int> -> seq<int>)
```

See the parentheses? That means a single `FSharpFunc` object is returned, and it is the function that you call with input.

As you can see, `input` isn't passed to the filtering function, nor is its type associated at all with the inferred parameterized types for `Seq`.

To fix this, you need to pass `input` to `Seq.filter`.